# How to add a new file association to Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

(Windows XP, Visual Studio 2010 Express (Web Developer))

I would like to add various file types to open in Visual Studio that it does not open by default, namely `.js`, `.html`, `.shtml`, `.css`, etc.

I tried looking for UI inside Visual Studio to add new file types, but I couldn't find anything, so I tried the naive approach of right clicking on the file -> Open With -> Choose Program -> Browse -> `c:\program files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpress.exe`. This almost works, except it starts a new instance of the IDE rather than opening a new tab the way `.cs` files do.

I've tried to go registry diving, exported the association for `.cs` files, and changing it to point to `.shtml` (for example), but this still spawns new windows.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.shtml]
"Content Type"="text/plain"
"PerceivedType"="text"
@="VWDExpress.cs.10.0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.shtml\OpenWithProgids]
"VSTA.cs.9.0"=""
"VWDExpress.cs.9.0"=""
"VWDExpress.cs.10.0"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.shtml\OpenWithProgids\Shared]
@="Shared key to keep this from being removed with install/uninstall of side-by-side components."

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.shtml\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"
```

I strongly suspect that doing this is the wrong way to go about this, but I can't find a better solution. Is there one?

Comment: It is done with the /dde option and ddeexec key on the retail edition.  Best thing to do is to look at an existing association first.

Answer (score 1):

Ive had the same issue so downloaded VWD with SP1 along with VS.PHP 2.10. Right clicked on a .php file and chose 'open with vs.php 2.10', checked the checkbox on bottom which saves settings.  Double clicking on a php file has been working since then. In order to be able to use it from a file manager like winscp i had to put 'explorer' as the editor executable. It works for my js html css and php files and opens them in the same VWD instance. Only pain may be that vs.php is to be paid for eventually and that you'd need to associate every extension you wish to work with.

Answer (score 0):

After you use naive approach to associate file with VWDExpress.exe, find a command in registry and add /EDIT parameter. I don't know if this works for Express versions, but for full Visual Studio this opens file in already open Visual Studio instance.

Answer (score 0):

Download [Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/#download) and open.

In my case I was associating `.php` files to Visual Studio 11, and to do this I simply copied the settings for `.cs` files. I've noted all steps below.

1. FIle Type Settings > Context Menu
2. Search `.php` (or whatever association) - note you can multi-select
3. Click next
4. Click *Add...* under the list
5. Enter the following data:

> **Command name:** Open
>
> **Program path:** C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /dde

[image: new association in default programs editor]

Now unfold the *Advanced Settings*, tick *Use DDE Message*, and  click *Edit*. Add the following:

> **Message:** Open("%1")
>
> **Application:** VisualStudio.11.0
>
> **Topic:** system

[image: editing dynamic data exchange properties of file association]

If you want to apply this to lots of files I suggest using the built in saving to registry option and creating a batch script with it.